# Setting up named routes within a subdomain group in Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have been working on a multi-tenant app and I'm trying to set up the routes in sub-domains according to the documentation:https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing

In my **web.php** route file, I have something like this:

```php
Route::domain('{account}.example.test')->group(function () {        
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');        
});
```

Right now, the problem is using named routes in blade, but I suppose I may run into the same problem eventually in my Controllers.

Whenever I try to used a named route like this:

**Blade Code**

```
<a href="{{ route('home') }}">Home</a>
```

I get the following error:

> Missing required parameters for [Route: home] [URI: home]. (View: /home/vagrant/Code/example/resources/views/example.blade.php)

I have found a way for solving this, you just have to:

```
<a href="{{ route('home', request('account')) }}">Home</a>
```

I also "solved" this using a helper...

```php
if (! function_exists('acctRoute')) {
    function acctRoute($name = '')
    {
        return route( $name, request('account'));
    }
}
```

So I can use it like:

```
<a href="{{ acctRoute('home') }}">Home</a>
```

But I'm still wondering if there's a cleaner way to do this, maybe with some middleware that always injects the parameter?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is my answer to my own question in case anyone needs this in the future:

From here I noticed that you can set default values for all routes under a middleware:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/urls#default-values

So... This is what I ended up doing

First create the middleware:

`php artisan make:middleware MyMiddleware`

Then update the handle method inside the created middleware as in the documentation example:

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    URL::defaults(['account' => request('account')]);

    return $next($request);
}
```

Then register the Middleware in Kernel.php

```php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    'mymiddle' => \App\Http\Middleware\MyMiddleware::class,
];
```

Then use it as any other middleware in your routes files:

```
Route::domain('{account}.example.test')->middleware('mymiddle')->group(function () {        
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');        
});
```

And finally, use the route helper function as usual:

```
<a href="{{ route('home') }}">Home</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could share the account (subdomain) variable across all views:

```
// AppServiceProvider

public function boot()
{
    View::share('subdomain', request('account'));
}

// blade
<a href="{{ route('home', $subdomain) }}">Home</a>
```

Another approach could use a service container binding:

```
// AppServiceProvider
$this->app->bind('account.route', function () {
    return route('home', request('route'));
});

// blade
<a href="{{ app('account.route') }}">Home</a>
```

Comment: A lil bit cleaner, but I really just want to pass the name for the route hehehe thanks!

Comment: Probably need to use the service container or a global helper method to achieve that. Added an example of the former.

Comment: Thanks Man! I ended up creating a middleware, but anyways thanks for the help!